# Will iOS apps still do background tasks when "Background App Refresh" is turned on even when the app is terminated?

Tags: ios, multitasking

In order words, if I force quit an app, will it still be able to do background tasks when "Background App Refresh" is enabled?

Comment: Is there a practical problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: Don't force quit apps.

Secondly: No, still do not force quit apps. You might think it is a good idea doing this from time to time - it's not.

Yes, background app refresh may still be run after the app has been force quit. Note that it is "may" and not "will" as is always the case with background app refresh.

Comment: why is closing apps (from the app switcher) bad?

Comment: Only close app from the app switch when the app has crashed - i.e. is not responding. Closing apps for any other reason is not a good idea. It will hurt performance and battery life - and waste your time.

Comment: I still frequently see people periodically swiping up all their apps in the mistaken belief it "saves battery". I do try to explain why it's a fallacy, but some still don't get it.